# EntityFramework.BulkInsert.SqlServerCe error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, sql-server-ce, bulkinsert

I've used Entity Framework with SQL Server CE in a project and I need to insert a large number of records into a table at a moment. So I Googled for a Bulk insert with Entity Framework and I found [this package on Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.BulkInsert.SqlServerCe/) that is a package for insert bulk insert using EF and SQL Server CE.

I've simply used this code:

```
  EntityFramework.BulkInsert.ProviderFactory
                    .Register<EntityFramework.BulkInsert.SqlServerCe.SqlCeBulkInsertProvider>("System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection");
  context.BulkInsert(tableInformation);
  context.SaveChanges();
```

But it didn't work properly and I've get this error:

> Additional information: Method 'Run' in type 'EntityFramework.BulkInsert.SqlServerCe.SqlCeBulkInsertProvider' from assembly 'EntityFramework.BulkInsert.SqlServerCe, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=630a17433349cb76' does not have an implementation.

I try to search for the error but I can't find any related result. Also I look at its [documentation](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/documentation) but there wasn't any sample or guidance for using SQL Server CE with its provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ErikEJ.SqlCeBulkCopy, available via NuGet or on CodePlex

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've installed it before but unfortunately there isn't any sample for using of Bulk method. Do you know how to use it?

Comment: Of course there is a sample: http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/ - and yes, I know how to use it, I created it! :-)

Comment: lol. I'm so sorry for my inattention. Can I use your library with EF 6? Could you give me a sample using EF?

Comment: The library simply supports adding data to a table, it is not directly related to EF - I have some sample here http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/06/inserting-many-rows-with-entity.html

Comment: I really appreciate for your replies. It is working now. Thank you indeed.